# What is the difference between the terms 'equation' and 'algorithm'?

Tags: algorithms, terminology

What is the difference between the terms 'equation' and 'algorithm'?  Can these terms be used interchangeably?

Comment: Reminds me of the old riddle, "what's the difference between Marilyn Monroe and a submarine?" (Znevyla Zbaebr vf n zbivr fgne; n fhoznevar vf n obng gung tbrf haqre jngre.)

Answer (score 4):

They cannot. An **equation** is a relation between two *expressions* $A,B$, stating that they are equal
$$A=B$$
An **algorithm** is a series of steps (usually in *pseudo-code*) to be taken in order to solve a given problem (or approximate the solution). An algorithm may for example consist of an initial guess $x_0$, an *iteration function* $f$ and the "code"
$$x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  I'm actually a Creative Writing major and writing a story where a character explains the difference... most laypeople wouldn't really know, I suppose.  :)

Comment: @mariamacmillan That's an interesting setup. In this case you could speak of an algorithm as a kind of **cooking recipe**, in a nutshell.

Answer (score 1):

No.
An **Algorithm** is like a flowchart representing a set of steps to achieve a particular goal.
An **Equation** expresses the relation between several variables.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

An equation is a proposition that asserts the equality of two quantities, whereas an algorithm is a set of steps to get from some initial quantities to some desired output. Therefore they cannot be used interchangeably.

An algorithm can be translated to some programming language to carry out the computation and may contain statements that appear to be equations but clearly are not such as $$x=x+1,$$ which means to set the variable x, to the current value of x plus 1.

Comment: The example(x=x+1) was interesting.

Comment: Mathematicians will evade such notations. More common is
$$x \leftarrow x+1$$

Answer (score 0):

An equation is usually a statement form. An algorithm is a way to determine the solution set of a statement form.

Answer (score 0):

An *equation*: A statement that asserts the equality of two expressions; e.g., $X = Y$.

An *algorithm*: A set of instructions that are to be performed that leads to an outcome.

Loosley speaking, an equation is a statement to be solved. An algorithm on the other hand will give you a set of instructions for solving it.

The two terms are not synonymous.